# check version compatibility in windows without writing any commands in command prompt or any commandline tools?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, version

I want to check which version of the following are compatible with each other. so that i can get the right jars from maven.

spring,hibernate,java.

how do i check version compatibility in windows without writing any commands in command prompt or any commandline tools?

Is it possible to check from any websites?

Comment: you could try the websites of spring and hibernate, they usually know with which versions spring and hibernate are compatible ....

Comment: Since you are using Maven, look into the 'pom' to see what dependencies are defined. https://mvnrepository.com is a good website to see the dependencies visualised and linked. Otherwise, as @Stultuske metioned, the libraries' own websites will be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) tool.

This will help you configure a `Maven` project, add required dependencies, and download starter code.